# Once I add session in edit form, I could not get selected values in dropdown

Tags: php

Once I add session in edit form, I could not get selected values in dropdown menu. I am using bootstrap framework. When I remove session from the same beginning it works.

edit.php file

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $car=$_POST['car']
?> 
<form method="post" action="">
<div class=from-group>
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1>Car</label>
    <select class="form-group" name="car" id="car" value="<?php echo $car; selected?>">
      <option value=<?php echo $car?> selected>
         <?php cars()?>
      </option>
</div>
</form>
```

I have created "cars" function in which I get values of all cars from database.

```
function cars(){
   $link = new mysqli("", "", "", "");
   $link = set_charset("utf8);

   $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM db_cars ORDER BY CarId")
   echo '<option value=""> Choose car </option>'
   while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
       echo '<option value = "'.$record['CarId']'"> . $record['CarName'].' </option>
   }
}
```

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a `<form>`? `<label>` and `mysqli_query(` are not closed. Please check your code.

Comment: Yes I do. I forgot to post it

Comment: first of all correct this  $link = set_charset("utf8"); instead of  $link = set_charset("utf8); also i think you start session two times.

Comment: I see in the HTML no semicolon (;) for `$car = $_POST['car']` that can be the problem also, also add it to the value in the `option ` and when you call the function `car()`

Answer (score 0):

The select element has no `name` attribute, so it cannot be a successful control (i.e. submit any data).

The form has no submit button, so there is no obvious way for you to trigger the form submission. (You have to submit the form in a new HTTP request to the server to run the PHP and get the data from the user).

Comment: It is unclear to me if I remove seession_start it works. once i add it it does not

Answer (score 0):

First, add the semicolons after every line when you use PHP. That can make a lot of troubles.

Second, some attributes have just one ("), like the label in the HTML.

Third, you are adding "something" called `selected` after echoing `$car`.

In the function `cars()` you are echoing without a semicolon (;) and just after doing a `while()` loop.

Check out all, you are missing very important and essential things

Also, I gonna guess this is not a "copy-paste" from your code, but if it's, you also are missing `</select>`

Comment: It is not copy pase. All those you have mentioned is written in my code. Thanks for reply. But I am wondering if I do not use session_start() it works. Once I add that line on the same beginning of code it does not work

Comment: are you including some other pages that also contains `session_start();`?

Comment: No I am including jquery files, connection to db, and functions file but seession_start is not in function file

Comment: Then I recommend you the copy-paste your exact code (overriding sensible information for Foo), not all, but things it requires. With the code above given, we only can tell you some errors.